# Reduce the overhead of httprequest by using hash in Android app

Tags: android, hash, httprequest

The user scenario is as the user use the application to request the files in the router, the router would send back a `file string`.(like JASON file but not)

It contains files or directories information. After parsing the string, it will create an `object array` so that I can push it to the `adapter` of a `listview`. As the user press on the directory icon, it would send an `http request` to request the `file string` again even if the files or directories information remains the same.

I just wonder whether I can hash the files and directories information to judge if the data has been changed or not. If it's not changed, I won't have to send another request.

But what information should be hashed and how to do so?

Is there any available plugin?

Please suggest some strategy to reduce the httpoverhead in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the files, then yes - you could create a checksum and write it at a known location, only reading entire file if the checksum's changed.  That known location could be inside each file, or in a separate file per directory - pros and cons depending on your needs and how files may be changed.

If you don't write the files, you'll have to dig a bit deeper to work out how to do this with whatever insight the router's providing you.  If the router-provided directory information includes any time stamps, checksums etc then you may be able to compare to the last time you downloaded the info and deduce which files have changed.

If not, you've no way of knowing if something's changed without downloading the files again, but you could take an attitude like "if it's been less than 10 seconds then who cares if it's changed - just show them the old data"... depends on your app whether that's sane.

If you want a pre-written checksum/hash - perhaps try MD5 - it's often used for file checksums on UNIX/Linux.